# How to control an Mcp41010 wiper position with an analog value

Tags: arduino, microchip, arduino-ide

I am using an Mcp41010 digipot chip and am wondering how to vary the wiper position of the chip with an analog input voltage that I can adjust, I need a way of decrementing(--) the wiper position if the voltage goes over a certain point and incrementing(++) the wiper position of the chip back to the normal position this is some code that i found that just fades the wiper position up and down I need a way of controlling it. I am still very new to arduino so sorry if my explanation was clear enough.

```
int CS_signal = 12;                      // Chip Select signal onsul pin 2 of Arduino
int CLK_signal = 52;                     // Clock signal on pin 4 of Arduino
int MOSI_signal = 51;                    // MOSI signal on pin 5 of Arduino
byte cmd_byte2 = B00010001 ;            // Command byte
int initial_value = 100;                // Setting up the initial value

void initialize() {                     // send the command byte of value 100 (initial value)
spi_out(CS_signal, cmd_byte2, initial_value);
}

void spi_out(int CS, byte cmd_byte, byte data_byte){                         // we need this function to send command byte and data byte to the chip

digitalWrite (CS, LOW);                                                 //  to start the transmission, the chip select must be low
spi_transfer(cmd_byte); // invio il COMMAND BYTE
delay(2);
spi_transfer(data_byte); // invio il DATA BYTE
delay(2);
digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);                                                 //     to stop the transmission, the chip select must be high
}

void spi_transfer(byte working) {
for(int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {                                           //      Set up a loop of 8 iterations (8 bits in a byte)
if (working > 127) { 
digitalWrite (MOSI_signal,HIGH) ;                                    // If the MSB is a 1 then set MOSI high
} else { 
digitalWrite (MOSI_signal, LOW) ; }                                  // If the MSB is a 0 then set MOSI low                                           

digitalWrite (CLK_signal,HIGH) ;                                        //  Pulse the CLK_signal high
working = working << 1 ;                                                // Bit-shift the working byte
digitalWrite(CLK_signal,LOW) ;                                          // Pulse the CLK_signal low
}
}

void setup() {
pinMode (CS_signal, OUTPUT);
pinMode (CLK_signal, OUTPUT);
pinMode (MOSI_signal, OUTPUT);

initialize();

Serial.begin(9600);                                                     // setting the serial speed
Serial.println("ready!");
}

void loop() {
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
spi_out(CS_signal, cmd_byte2, i); 
Serial.println(i); delay(10); 
}
for (int i = 255; i > 0; --i) {
spi_out(CS_signal, cmd_byte2, i);
Serial.println(i);
delay(10);
}
}
```

Comment: You should init SPI before use it. No need to config MOSI, MISO, SCK manually. Look at official SPI example as starting point.

Comment: I think I have found the answer to my problem I will make an answer as i cannot fit my code into a comment.

Comment: @Vladimir Tsykunov - At the moment my code is working in a basic sense when i have more details I will get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int CS_signal = 12;                      // Chip Select signal onsul pin 2     of Arduino
int CLK_signal = 52;                     // Clock signal on pin 4 of Arduino
int MOSI_signal = 51;                    // MOSI signal on pin 5 of Arduino
byte cmd_byte2 = B00010001 ;            // Command byte
int initial_value = 100;                // Setting up the initial value

void initialize() {                     // send the command byte of value 100 (initial value)
spi_out(CS_signal, cmd_byte2, initial_value);
```

}

```
void spi_out(int CS, byte cmd_byte, byte data_byte){                        // we need this function to send command byte and data byte to the chip

digitalWrite (CS, LOW);                                                 // to start the transmission, the chip select must be low
spi_transfer(cmd_byte); // invio il COMMAND BYTE
delay(2);
spi_transfer(data_byte); // invio il DATA BYTE
delay(2);
digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);                                                 // to stop the transmission, the chip select must be high
}

void spi_transfer(byte working) {
for(int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {                                           // Set up a loop of 8 iterations (8 bits in a byte)
 if (working > 127) { 
   digitalWrite (MOSI_signal,HIGH) ;                                    //  If the MSB is a 1 then set MOSI high
 } else { 
   digitalWrite (MOSI_signal, LOW) ; }                                  // If the MSB is a 0 then set MOSI low                                           

digitalWrite (CLK_signal,HIGH) ;                                        // Pulse the CLK_signal high
working = working << 1 ;                                                // Bit-shift the working byte
digitalWrite(CLK_signal,LOW) ;                                          // Pulse the CLK_signal low
}
}

void setup() {
pinMode (CS_signal, OUTPUT);
pinMode (CLK_signal, OUTPUT);
pinMode (MOSI_signal, OUTPUT);

initialize();

Serial.begin(9600);                                                     // setting the serial speed
Serial.println("ready!");
}

  void loop() {
  //  read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  if(sensorValue <= 200){
  //  Convert the analog reading (which goes from 0 - 1023) to a voltage (0 - 5V):
   float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);
   //   print out the value you read:
   Serial.println(voltage);

    int i = sensorValue;{
    spi_out(CS_signal, cmd_byte2, i); 
    Serial.println(i); 

   }
   }

   }
```

Comment: I kind of got split up but this is the code that works for what i want to do.

Comment: It is good that you are doing low level setups from your own code. When issues will be solved better move to exising Arduino libraries, this will help saving your time in future.